# Running a report synchronously and displaying its chart in a visualforce page.

Tags: apex, visualforce, reports-api, analytics-api

I am using `<analytics:reportChart/>` tag inside a visualforce page where the reportId attribute value is dynamically retrieved from associated Controller. The controller also runs the report synchronously after adding a filter value to the report.

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="ReportController">
    <analytics:reportChart reportId="{!ReportId}"></analytics:reportChart>
</apex:page>
```

**ApexClass**

```
public class ReportController 
{
    public string getReportId()
    {
        string reportID = '';
        List<Report> reportList = [select ID, DeveloperName from Report 
                                  where DeveloperName = 'myTestReport'];
        reportId = (string)reportList.get(0).get('Id');

        Reports.ReportDescribeResult myReportResult = Reports.ReportManager.describeReport(reportId);
        Reports.ReportMetadata myReportMetaData = myReportResult.getReportMetadata();

        Reports.ReportFilter myFilters = myReportMetaData.getReportFilters()[0];
         system.debug('--------->'+myFilters);

        //set the filter value
        myFilters.setValue('OL-000040');
        Reports.ReportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId, myReportMetaData);

        return reportID;
    }
}
```

I see that the report is running successfully but the chart that is getting displayed is NOT capturing the filtered data from the report. Anyone guide me through the right way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you find answer for this ?

Comment: @brahmajitammana Nope, I did not.

Answer (score 0):

Replace second last line with following and try again

```
Reports.ReportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId, myReportMetaData,true);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this solution is different and what it fixes.